# How to configure pivotal tc in Eclipse to use log4j configuration instead of its own loggingmanager?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, spring-tool-suite, pivotal-tc

In Spring Tool Suite's (STS) version of Eclipse, Pivotal TC insists on using its logging manager, which subterfuges my log4j.xml .

Part of my running the server in the IDE is to ensure that the whole package including spring and logging config in dev will work in dev server as in production Tomcat. Besides other tests, I also need to test the log4j.xml config.

But Pivotal TC circumvents and subterfuges my use of log4j.xml and so I need to find a way to remove that pivotal tc behaviour. I wish to know how to tell pivotl tc to use log4j.xml.

Since STS already provided a Tomcat, I see no point in installing another Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using tc Server 3.2.x with Tomcat 8.5 in STS?

log4j is no longer supported on Tomcat 8.5.  You will need to use log4j2 and use the standard log4j2 mechanism to capture 
java.util.logging output and redirect it.

If my assumptions are incorrect, please provide more information about the versions and env you are using.

Thanks.